# Why can't I throw an exception when a Future mocked object's method is executed?

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to write a test case that needs to cover a catch block. The catch block catches `InterruptedException` or `ExecutionException`, both are in the method signature of the `.get()` method of the `Future` object. I am trying to simulate an InterruptedException using `thenThrow` from Mockito, when the `.get()` method of the Future object is called, so the control goes into the uncovered catch block.

futureData is a `List<Future<Class>>` type, and result is a `Future<Class>` object.

```
futureData.forEach(result -> {
    try {
   enginesData.add(result.get()); // the method I am using to force an exception using Mockito
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
   // the catch block I am trying to cover
    }
});
```

Below is my test case:

```
@Test
public void testInterruptedException () throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    ...
    InterruptedException interruptedException = new InterruptedException("Interrupted Exception");
    when(oneFutureData.get()).thenThrow(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(interruptedException));
    ...
}
```

I tried writing both `thenThrow` and `doThrow` consecutively, but it is still not covering the catch block. Could it be because I am trying to mock a Future object and mocking a method from the Future class?

Comment: Is `futureData` empty?

Comment: If you are looking to catch an `InterruptedException` from the `get` call, then why not simply `thenThrow(interruptedException)` on that call ?  After all, a `catch (InterruptedException ` is not going to catch a `CompletableFuture`

Comment: @dan1st no it contains a ``List<Future<Class>>`` containing two ``Future<Class>`` elements. It might have something to do with it being a future that Mockito isn't detecting the method being called therefore it did not throw the exception?

Comment: @racraman yes I did. I have a ``when(futureData.get()).thenThrow(interruptedException)`` on my test case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something in your
`// the catch block I am trying to cover` - block.
For instance, you would call some logger to write the Exception to the log file, or anything else.
The trick is that you need to spy on whatever you call in the `// the catch block I am trying to cover`
Then you can check, if this method was really called in your catch block.
Check out this example, on how to achieve this:

```java
package de.playground.so74236327;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
// see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74236327/why-cant-i-throw-an-exception-when-a-future-mocked-objects-method-is-executed
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) // needed for the @Mock annotation
public class FutureExceptionTest {
    @Mock
    public Future<Class> futureMock;
    @Test
    public void testInterruptedException() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        MyService mySpy = spy(new MyService());
        ExampleProductionCode exampleProductionCode = new ExampleProductionCode(mySpy);// contains 2 real Future<Class> objects.
        List<Future<Class>> futureData = exampleProductionCode.getFutureData();
        InterruptedException interruptedException = new InterruptedException("Interrupted Exception");
        // Future<Class> oneFutureData = Mockito.mock(Future.class);
        //when(oneFutureData.get()).thenThrow(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(interruptedException)); that doesn't even compile
        when(futureMock.get()).thenThrow(interruptedException);
        futureData.add(futureMock); // add another Future<Class> object, but this time it's just a mock object
        verify(mySpy, times(0)).logError(interruptedException);//nothing has happend yet
        exampleProductionCode.collectAsyncResults(); // calling the 3 Future.get() methods inside
        // 3 cases:
        // 1st: with the completableFuture.completeExceptionally(e);
        // 2nd: FutureTask<Class> throwing an exception inside the task
        // 3rd: comes from the  oneFutureData mock object above
        verify(mySpy, times(3)).logError(any(Exception.class));
    }
}
```

Your production code would look similar to these lines:

```java
package de.playground.so74236327;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
public class ExampleProductionCode {
    List<Future<Class>> futureData;
    EnginesData enginesData;
    MyService myService;
    public ExampleProductionCode(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
        futureData = new ArrayList<Future<Class>>();
        enginesData = new EnginesData();
        Future<Class> oneFutureData = createAndStartAsyncTask();
        futureData.add(oneFutureData);
        Future<Class> twoFutureData = createAndStartFutureTask();
        futureData.add(twoFutureData);
    }
    public EnginesData getEngineData() {
        return enginesData;
    }
    public List<Future<Class>> getFutureData() {
        return futureData;
    }
    public Future<Class> createAndStartAsyncTask() {
        CompletableFuture<Class> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                // and do whatever you need to do or throw an exception in case something went wrong
                throw new InterruptedException(); // just the exceptional case here for demonstration purposes
                //return null; // return normally if there would be not exception
            } catch (Exception e) {
                completableFuture.completeExceptionally(e);
                // don't call  completableFuture.cancel(false )! that wouldn't work
                // don't call  completableFuture.cancel(true )! that wouldn't work either
            }
        });
        return completableFuture;
    }
    public Future<Class> createAndStartFutureTask() {
        FutureTask<Class> ftask = new FutureTask<Class>(() -> {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            throw new InterruptedException(); // just the exceptional case here for demonstration purposes
            //return MySOClass.class; // return normally if there would be not exception
        });
        ftask.run();
        return ftask;
    }
    public void collectAsyncResults() {
        ExampleProductionCode.EnginesData enginesData = this.getEngineData();
        futureData.forEach(result -> {
            try {
                enginesData.add(result.get()); // the method I am using to force an exception using Mockito
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                // "the catch block I am trying to cover"
                // if you want to cover this catchblock you need to
                // 1. execute some method here, and then
                // 2. spy on this method, so you can check in you test, whether this method was really called with the correct parameters
                myService.logError(e);
            }
        });
    }
    public class EnginesData {
        public void add(Class aclass) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

and

```java
package de.playground.so74236327;

public class MyService {
        public void logError(Exception e) {
            //do something
        }
}
```

try yourself:
`git clone --depth 1 --branch so74236327 git@github.com:bodote/playground.git`
look at the `package de.playground.so74236327` and run `FutureExceptionTest`